# Prolog is/2, arguments not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: parsing, prolog, abstract-syntax-tree, instantiation-error

I'm working on an assignment where I have created a parser for a prefix-notation arithmetic language. I need to write a predicate which builds an ast for any given value V (i.e. generate an ast A such that whenever A is evaluated it's value is V). My idea was simple enough:

```
genAst(Val, Env, Ast) :-
   ev(Ast, Env, Val).
```

where ev is the evaluate-predicate. When I run this I get the error on the title concerning this part of the ev-predicate:

```
ev(xer_(power(N)), Env, V) :-
   integer(N),
   V is Env^N. %THIS LINE
```

where both V and N are unbound. I'm struggling to think of another elegant way to do this, does anyone know how I could make prolog generate integers for these two variables?

I hope this was understandable :)

Comment: Oops sorry I read "bound" rather than "unbound". In that case, you can't use `is`. The left must be a single, unbound variable, and the right must be all bound variables. Prolog won't enumerate possible solutions to an `is/2` expression.

Comment: Sure, you could use `var/1` or `nonvar/1`.

Comment: OK, is there any way I can ask Prolog for example 4 =:= 2^X ? This also gives me "arguments not instantiated", but Ive tried 4 == 2^X and 4 = 2^X to no avail

Comment: The `=:=` operator requires that everything be instantiated. By inquiring `4 =:= 2^X` I assume you mean you want `log2(4)`. So you could use `X is log10(4)/log10(2).` then use your prolog interpreters other arithmetic functions to determine if it's an integer. Or, since the base is `2` you could easily create a predicate that does `log2` using shifts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posed, your problem seems unsolvable, then I think I would approach the whole problem differently, generating *all* ASTs up to a max num of tokens.

```
genAst(Val, Env, Ast) :-
    length(Tokens, N),
    (N > 10, !, fail ; true),
    phrase(sum(Ast), Tokens),
    ev(Ast, Env, Val).

sum(sum(A,B)) --> [+], mul(A), sum(B).
sum(N) --> mul(N).

mul(mul(N,X)) --> [*], xer(X), num(N).
mul(N) --> xer(N).

xer(exp(x,N)) --> [^,x], num(N).
xer(var(x)) --> [x].
xer(N) --> num(N).

%num(num(X)) --> [X], {var(X) -> between(1,9,X) ; integer(X)}.
num(num(X)) --> [X], {X=2;X=3}.
```

yields

```
?- genAst(6,2,A).
A = sum(num(3), num(3)) ;
A = mul(num(3), var(x)) ;
A = mul(num(3), num(2)) ;
A = mul(num(2), num(3)) ;
A = sum(mul(num(2), var(x)), var(x)) ;
A = sum(mul(num(2), var(x)), num(2)) ;
A = sum(mul(num(2), num(2)), var(x)) ;
A = sum(mul(num(2), num(2)), num(2)) ;
A = sum(exp(x, num(2)), var(x)) ;
A = sum(exp(x, num(2)), num(2)) ;
A = sum(var(x), sum(var(x), var(x))) ;
A = sum(var(x), sum(var(x), num(2))) ;
A = sum(var(x), sum(num(2), var(x))) ;
A = sum(var(x), sum(num(2), num(2))) ;
A = sum(var(x), mul(num(2), var(x))) ;
A = sum(var(x), mul(num(2), num(2))) ;
A = sum(var(x), exp(x, num(2))) ;
A = sum(num(2), sum(var(x), var(x))) ;
A = sum(num(2), sum(var(x), num(2))) ;
A = sum(num(2), sum(num(2), var(x))) ;
A = sum(num(2), sum(num(2), num(2))) ;
A = sum(num(2), mul(num(2), var(x))) ;
A = sum(num(2), mul(num(2), num(2))) ;
A = sum(num(2), exp(x, num(2))) ;
false.
```

Limiting the length of the input in this DCG is required because of the right recursive non terminal sum//1

Answer (score 2):

Use [`library(clpfd)`](/tags/clpfd/info) or the newer `clpz`. It contains exactly that kind of functionality. And there is no need to generate concrete values, as long as you do not need them!

```
?- X #= Y^Z.
   Y^Z#=X.
?- X #= Y^Z, [Y,Z]ins 1..3.
   Y^Z#=X, X in 1..sup, Y in 1..3, Z in 1..3.
?- X #= Y^Z, [Y,Z]ins 1..3, labeling([], [Y,Z]).
   X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1
;  X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 2
;  X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 3
;  X = 2, Y = 2, Z = 1
;  X = 4, Y = 2, Z = 2
;  X = 8, Y = 2, Z = 3
;  X = 3, Y = 3, Z = 1
;  X = 9, Y = 3, Z = 2
;  X = 27, Y = 3, Z = 3.
```